# Why doesn't overflow: hidden work in this case?

Tags: html, css

In the `bookmark_matrix` in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sjD24/14/

I'm trying to hide content outside of the 500 px width

by setting

```
overflow:hidden
```

I'm not getting the desired effect as it wraps to the next line instead.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

The two examples I've seen show overflow working with vertical content, I'm not sure if this implies it does not work with horizontal content.

Please note that I do not want it to wrap.  Perhaps that would have been a better title.

Comment: If you want a flexible height on the bookmark matrix to allow lots of different types to be displayed then you will need to specifiy widths on the inner elements that are much wider than the container with the overflow:hidden on it, otherwise they will just wrap.

Comment: that's what I did and it worked, don't know why.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjD24/27/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sjD24/33/?

Comment: It's because the inner elements if not having a specific width set will simply become the width of their parent element. Therefore wrapping anything within them. Setting a specific width stops that wrap and forces them beyond the width of their parent, making the overflow:hidden useful again.

Comment: @jo8691 - `white-space:no-wrap` is another option.  I take it white-space means content ( text, links, etc ).  Its misnomers like that, that make me not look forward to CSS "porgramming"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no `height` set, so the div's height expands as needed. There's no overflow.

You could do something like this:

```
#bookmark_matrix{
    border: 1px dotted #222222;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: but I want to prevent horizontal wrapping, while keeping the my height large.

Comment: I want to be able to extend my rows with out them effecting the rows below them.

Comment: In that case, add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.bookmark_row` styles